# Live-action vampire movie where a vampire drinks a horse's blood

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I saw this live-action vampire movie a very long time ago when I was a kid, so I don't remember much.

1. The movie was made before 2006.
2. Near the beginning of the movie, a vampire takes a horse to the stable and then bites into the horse and drinks blood directly from it.
3. There was a human female dancing with a vampire male in a castle alone by themselves.
4. There was a vampire female who shot intestines out of her stomach to attack a human.
5. A coffin opens, and a vampire emerges along with a bunch of insects (cockroaches, maybe?).

Comment: Was it our time or some medieval? Was there any "magic levitation", "mind control", etc?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi It is not modern time. I don't remember magic or mind control so not sure.